# Split (denormalize) 2 Child/Parent columns into Multiple columns (based on how many levels of Parents)

Tags: sql-server

I have my ChildID and ParentID in 2 columns, however I want to split these columns into several columns but all still pointing toward their parent, and if applicable, also point to the parent of that parent.

It might be the case that the dataset has only 3 levels as depicted below, but in some cases there may be 4 levels as well, so that made it more difficult for, since it has to be somewhat dynamic.

Below is my current dataset, a Child/Parent table:

```
            ID, PARID,
            1,  
            1,  
            10,     1
            11,     1
            20,     2
            21,     2
            100,    10
            101,    10
            110,    11
            111,    11
            200,    20
            201,    20
            210,    21
            211,    21
```

And how I want it to be like is the following:

```
            LVL1    LVL2    LVL3
            1,
            1,
            1,      10,
            1,      11,
            2,      20,
            2,      21,
            1,      10,     100,
            1,      10,     101,
            1,      11,     110,
            1,      11,     111,
            2,      20,     200,
            2,      20,     201,
            2,      21,     210,
            2,      21,     211,
```

The ID names are not necessarily how I want them to be called, but it's just as example. Also, It is not always the case that the Childs always include the ID of the Parents.

I cannot find the right info online, I only end up finding how to create a Child/Parent table, instead of trying the opposite.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: 
Thanks to the reaction so far I show my actual data, although in reality it has 12000 rows AND as you can see it has an automatically generated unique key, which might be necessary to know:

```
                                OBJECTID,GROUNDID,MAINGROUNDID, 
                                1,      024,    
                                2,      025,    
                                3,      026,    
                                4,      02610,  026,
                                5,      02620,  026,
                                6,      02630,  026,
                                7,      02640,  026,
                                8,      02650,  026,
                                9,      027,    
                                10,     028,    
                                11,     029,    
                                12,     030,    
                                13,     03010,  030,
                                14,     03020,  030,
                                15,     03030,  030,
                                16,     03040,  030,
                                17,     030401, 03040,
```

Edit, results so far, double rows however:

```
                                    GROUNDID,Lvl1,Lvl2,Lvl3,Lvl4  
                                    006     006     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    007     007     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    008     008     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    009     009     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    010     010     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    011     011     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    014     014     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    015     015     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    016     016     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    017     017     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    018     018     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    019     019     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    020     020     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    021     021     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    022     022     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    023     023     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    024     024     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    025     025     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    026     026     NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    02610   026     02610   NULL    NULL
                                    02620   026     02620   NULL    NULL
                                    02630   026     02630   NULL    NULL
                                    02640   026     02640   NULL    NULL
                                    02650   026     02650   NULL    NULL
                                    02610   02610   NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    02620   02620   NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    02630   02630   NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    02640   02640   NULL    NULL    NULL
                                    02650   02650   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Kind regards,
Igor

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using a standard recursive CTE to build the hierarchy and a little XML to parse the columns

**Example**

```
;with cteP as (
      Select ID
            ,PARID 
            ,PathID = cast(ID as varchar(max))
      From   YourTable
      Where  PARID is Null
      Union  All
      Select ID  = r.ID
            ,PARID  = r.PARID 
            ,PathID = p.PathID+concat(',',r.ID)
      From   YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.PARID  = p.ID)
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  cteP A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Lvl1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','int')
                      ,Lvl2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','int')
                      ,Lvl3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','int')
                      ,Lvl4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','int')
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace(PathID,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) B(xDim)
             ) B
  Order By PathID
```

**Returns**

[image]

> **EDIT - UPDATED FOR REAL DATA**

```
;with cteP as (
      Select GROUNDID
            ,MAINGROUNDID 
            ,PathID = cast(GROUNDID as varchar(max))
      From   YourTable
      Where  MAINGROUNDID is Null
      Union  All
      Select GROUNDID      = r.GROUNDID
            ,MAINGROUNDID  = r.MAINGROUNDID 
            ,PathID = p.PathID+concat(',',r.GROUNDID)
      From   YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.MAINGROUNDID  = p.GROUNDID)
Select A.GROUNDID
      ,B.*
 From  cteP A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Lvl1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Lvl2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Lvl3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Lvl4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(50)')
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace(PathID,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) B(xDim)
             ) B
  Order By PathID
```

**Returns**

[image]

> **EDIT 2**

I'm assuming your source data looks something like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I tried it and somehow I got 0 rows. I added to the main description how my real data looks like. Maybe that will be more clear.

Comment: @titatovenaar See EDIT / Update.  Perhaps next time you will supply a more representative sample.

Comment: I agree, and I think that even my second try wasn't representative enough, since I get this error: "Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "PathID" of recursive query "cteP".". However, when I cast r.Ground also as varchar(max), it doesn't throw an error, but it again shows me the columns but with 0 rows data.

Comment: @titatovenaar Just curious... do the top level MAINGROUNDID have NULL values or empty strings ''  ?

Comment: The MAINGROUNDID is entirely blank. If i try to select where MAINGROUNDID is NULL I get 0 results. So they might be simply blank I guess

Comment: I found indeed a similar solution, and that works, I get results. Thanks! Though many rows are somehow double. Check it out in the edit

Answer (score -1):

For me your design is wrong. You have a `Person` entity, with a many-to-many relationship with itself:
- one person can have several parents
- one person can be the parent of 0 or more children.

In the relational model, a many-to-many relationship is represented by a relationship table. You should therefore have 2 tables:

- Persons: ID, Name, BirthDate,...
- RelationShip: ParentId, ChildId

This will allow you to represent ANY depth of parent/child relationship.

Comment: Fair enough, but in reality, which I didn't add but might be necessary: all have a unique automatically generated key: 1,2,3,4,etc.

Comment: @titatovenaar I don't think that impacts my answer nor the design

Comment: This means I don't entirely get what you are saying. I have a transaction table on which I want to be able to filter with the OBJECT dimension table I show above. Here I can select a GROUNDID, but if there is any child underneath it, it doesn't show the transactions that should actually be there as well. I don't see how the two split tables that you prefer help. Can you explain? (also: I actually have no option to change the tables, it's a design within a system I am not allowed to change unfortunately!)